# Sql Comparison where values of Table1 not found in Table2 and showing result as Table3

Tags: sql, comparison

I was trying someting like:

```
Select Items 
From Table1 
Where Not Exists (
    Select Items 
    From Table2 
    Where Table2.Items = Table1.Items) As Table3.Items
```

but somehow not working so can anywone tell me how can i achive this?

Comment: What do you mean by `giving result in Table3`? Should the result be `inserted` into table3?

Comment: Do you mean the SQL doesn't give expected result or the code gives you an error or runs without giving expected results. Could you paste the relevant code around your SQL here?

Comment: Table3 is not actually another table thats created before.. 
Its just gonna show the result of the query as Table3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a new table with this results, you can try this:

```
Select Items 
Into Table3
From Table1 
Where Not Exists (Select Items From Table2 Where Table2.Items = Table1.Items)
```

Comment: @BerkerYüceer - This is creating a new permanent table. If you just want to use it on another query, but don't want to create it as a table, you can use it as a derived table: `SELECT .. FROM (SELECT Itmes FROM Table1 WHERE Not Exists.....) AS Table3

Comment: yea i tried that up there but seems like i ve mistaken at the usage of SELECT * FROM (....) AS TABLE3. it worked now thanks..

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for rows in `t3` that do exist in `t1` but not in `t2`, try:

```
select  t3.Items 
from    table3 t3
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    table1 t1
        where   t1.Items = t3.items
        )
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    table2 t2
        where   t2.Items = t3.items
        )
```

Comment: i guess you have misunderstood me. i use Table3 only for showing the results from comparison made between Table1 and Table2 but this is another helpfull answer that is valuable to me so +1.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is `except`:

```
select *
from
(
    Select Items 
    From Table1
    except
    Select Items 
    From Table2
) as Table3
```